# How to change url params (query_string) in django rest framework before handle request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Because I need compatible with old client.
I use django-rest-framework and django_filter.
For example, when I recevie an request http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/exercises/?pk=13, i want change the params so http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/exercises/?id=13.

Others:
http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/exercises/?displayName=ABC
change to
http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/exercises/?display_name=ABC

http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/exercises/?target=1,2
change to
http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/exercises/?target=1&target=2

Is there any place I can write code before handle the request?
I try to change request.environ['QUERY_STRING'] and request.META['QUERY_STRING'] in middleware, but not work.

Thanks.

Comment: i think you can do it but I worked mostly with BE so I don't know how to handle your scenario from FE

Comment: Could you please tell me more about "BE" and "FE"？

Comment: BE means Backend and FE means Front end

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can make use of the `RedirectView` and override the `get_redirect_url` method to **map** the change in query params.

For implementation details, you can refer to the official [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview).

Answer (score -1):

You can use django's [`redirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) function for this. For that in your old views just redirect it to your new views.

A simple Example -

```py
def my_old_view(request,pk):
    ...
    return redirect(f'/api/excersise/?id={pk}')
```

So if someone enters your old URL it will be redirected to new one without any issues.

Comment: I use django-rest-framework ModelViewSet and django-filter，seems I can't use redirect in ModelViewSet

Comment: Maybe this is right, I try it.